# phantomjs doesn't show rendered page

Tags: phantomjs

I am newbie with phantomjs and trying to figure out how it works. I take this example

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('test');
page.open('https://github.com/', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

put to the file and execute

```
./phantomjs phantomjs-2.0.0-macosx/examples/github.js
```

Output is

```
test
```

and nothing more. What I need is some pdf file with rendered page.

Comment: Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the viewportSize and adding more detail to the render function

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };
page.open("https://github.com", function start(status) {
  page.render('github.pdf', {format: 'pdf', quality: '100'});
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: same,just viod output

Comment: Are you checking the folder your project is in?